# Tornado Templating with {% code %} {% end %}

Tags: python, templates, tornado

Is there any option to extend the tornado web template with the option inside the html template

```
{% code %}
  # Python code
{% end %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such option. Tornado's templates are fairly liberal in allowing python code directly in the template, especially with the `{% set %}` directive (which can include any single-line statement, not just a variable assignment), but it is not possible to use multi-line statements except for the ones that have corresponding template directives (`{% for %}`, `{% if %}`, `{% try %}`, and `{% while %}`)

Comment: Hi @Ben Darnell. But i have seen some where using {% code %} in tornado combination. Is there any alternate to add such feature?

Comment: Tornado templates have never supported a `{% code %}` directive; if you saw it somewhere it must have been in some other template system.